# Is "who did the shooting?" a natural thing to say in this context?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Man 1 - *They were shooting at me.*

Man 2 - *How can you be sure that it wasn't your friend **who did the shooting**?*

Is "who did the shooting" perfectly natural in this context or are there a much more natural things to say instead?

Comment: It sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

"Who did the shooting?" is a question more likely to be asked if you are discussing a "far-off" event that you were not present for. If you hear a story about a shooting on the other side of town a natural question would be "Who did the shooting?" or perhaps "Who was the shooter?"

If you are talking to a friend about an event they are very familiar with, it would sound more natural to say "How can you be sure it wasn't your friend **who was shooting at you**?" This phrasing emphasizes the *friend* who was there and lets them know you care about their story; saying that the shooting "was done" has a more clinical or analytic tone that wouldn't be appropriate if you are talking to someone who experienced the event.